# Count the number of ID - Python

Tags: python, count

I am looking to count the number of time an id occurs a put it in a new column in python

Basically it would be translating this code in R into python

```
library(dplyr)
ren2 <- ren2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(count=n())
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. It's not clear, for example, what you mean by "column".

Comment: Where are you stuck with your current attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('ID').transform('count')
```